# Laravel - Update multiple rows value with a form

Tags: php, laravel

I am listing many rows in a table and I AM trying to edit them with a drop down menu that exists in each row. The code below is fine but it will store only the last (S_Rank) value (which is the column I want to change) what would be the best way to get each row input. I know the issue that the form is not an array, what would be the way to make it an array

My view

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'AbstractsController@UpdateRank' , 'method' => 'post' ]) !!}
<table id="myTable" class ="table table-striped">

<thead>
        <td><h4>Student Name</h4></td>
        <td><h4>Student Rank</h4></td>
</thead>

@foreach($applications as $application)
<tbody>
<tr>

<td><h5>{{$application->Student_Name}}</h5></td>

<td><h5>

{{Form::select('Ranking' ,$ranks,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' =>$application->S_Rank] )}} 
{{Form::hidden('Student_ids[]',  $application->S_ID)}}

</h5></td>

</tr>

@endforeach

</tbody>
</table>

{{Form::Submit('Save New Ranking',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My controller

```
foreach(request('Student_ids') as $S_ID){
            $application = Application::where('S_ID' , $S_ID)->get();
            $application->S_Rank =  $request-> input('Ranking');
            $application->save();}
```

I am trying to update each row with the inputted value from each dropdown menu

Comment: where does `request('Student_ids')` come from?

Comment: ops, the hidden form meant to be Student_ids[], edited it correctly @khartnett

Comment: It looks like you have a 'ranking' drop down for each row. Do you want the dropdown to update just the application of that row? or update the ranking of every application that has that S_ID? How it is now it looks like you're trying to update every application ranking of every student_id

Comment: I want each dropdown to update that single row (that application)@khartnett

Comment: One last question. Does Application have a unique ID? or is S_ID it's unique id?

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answer yourselve. I think what you need is to change your `$ranks` var to `$ranks[]` because you are actually only taking the last value they chose in your select, that way, you are storing your ranks in a one dimenssion array that should correspont with your Student_ids[] hidden array

Comment: had to change the 'Ranking' to 'Rankings[]' and worked. $ranks is not where I store the user input, the $ranks lists the available rankings. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well at least that was the answer, have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the ranking per application, you'll need to know which ranking value goes to which application. Assuming S_ID is a unique identifier for Application, you could do something like this in your view:

```
<h5>
{{Form::select('Ranking[' . $application->S_ID . ']' ,$ranks,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' =>$application->S_Rank] )}} 
</h5>
```

Then in your controller:

```
foreach(request('Ranking') as $S_ID => $rank){
        $application = Application::where('S_ID' , $S_ID)->first();
        $application->S_Rank = $rank;
        $application->save();}
```